# How to only Run one time a function

Tags: php

I have the function bellow, and I want it only to run one time after the login, like, the user can do as many logins as he likes per day, but I only want the function to run on the first login, and never more.

When I call it like on the second piece of code, the function run on every login.

```
    function updateDiasFimAno ()
    {   
        //declaração de variaveis
        $currentYear = date("Y");
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
        $newYear = $currentYear."-01-01";
        $userID = $_SESSION['utilizador'];
        $objectDB = new Dbh;
        $objectDBU = new Dbh;


        //caso estejamos no dia de ano novo..
        if($currentDate == $newYear)
        {

            //ir à base de dados buscar os dados do user
            $q = $objectDB->connect()->query("SELECT diasRestantes, tipoRegimeID FROM utilizadores WHERE idUtilizadores = '$userID'");

            //criar uma tabela com os dados
            $row = $q->fetch();

            $diasRestantesL = $row['diasRestantes'];
            $tipoRegime = $row['tipoRegimeID'];

            if($tipoRegime == 2)
            {
                $diasRestantesA = 22;
                $diasRestantesA = $diasRestantesA + $diasRestantesL;
                //atualizar na base de dados
                $qU = $objectDBU->connect()->query("UPDATE utilizadores SET diasRestantes = '$diasRestantesA' WHERE idUtilizadores = '$userID'");

            }
            else if($tipoRegime == 1)
            {   
                //tras o numero de anos que passaram...20..30 etc
                $year = $_SESSION['years'];
                //dividir o numero de anos por 10 para obter o numero de dias a mais
                $diasMais = ($years/10);
                //numero de dias Default;
                $diasRestantesA = 22;
                //dias atuais é igual aos 22 mais os que sobraram do ano anterior, mais os de cada 10 anos a mais depois da data de admissao
                $diasRestantesA = $diasRestantesA + $diasRestantesL + $diasMais;

                $qU = $objectDBU->connect()->query("UPDATE utilizadores SET diasRestantes = '$diasRestantesA' WHERE idUtilizadores = '$userID'");
            }
        }

    }
```

The call on page:

```
    <?php $aux = new FeriasController();
    $auxF = new FeriasController();
    $aux->oneMoreDay();?>
```

Comment: I really can't see how those two code blocks are related. It also seems odd that you're creating two different instances of the same controller.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save on the database the information, such as `lastLoginDay`.

Then in your function:

- if the actual time is the same day as `lastLoginDay`, return without doing nothing else
- Otherwise, run the function and update the field `lastLoginDay` with the actual day.

Comment: Thank u for the help! I thought I could do it without changing the DB, but it seems to not be possible!

Comment: Well, you need to store that information somewhere. You could use a file instead of the DB, but it's better and more performant to use the database capabilities. You could create a different table, with only `user_id` and `last_login_day`, just for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

Create a column in the users table called has_ever_logged or something like that and set it to 0 by default.

On the login, check if that column of that user is set to 0. If it is, run the function and set it to 1. If it is not, do something else

Comment: thank u, i thought it would be possible without making changes on the DB, but it seems that is not, thank u a lot for the answer!

Comment: Well you could actually run it just after the registration I think

Comment: Would stay with the same problem, cause on every registration it will update, i think the solution is changing the DB. Thank u!

Comment: Every user registrates only once, so it would run once for user. Wasn't this what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @JorgeSá - _"cause on every registration it will update"_ - Isn't the update user-specific? Or are you asking how to update some global value on the first log in  per day, no matter the user?

Comment: @Donny I dont have registration, only login, so the user can login as many times as he likes..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I want to update on the specific user-login ! but only one time!